# date selection problem in android using date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I have two date picker in an activity, I want to show first date picker selected date in another date picker ..can anyone suggest how can I do this
.I want to show the previous selected date in the next date picker

```
final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                // date picker dialog
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                mytext.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
//                               
                            }
                        }, year, month, day);
```

```
 final Calendar cldrNext = Calendar.getInstance();
                int dayNext = cldrNext.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int monthNext = cldrNext.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int yearNext = cldrNext.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                // date picker dialog
//                int mn=cldrNext.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//                Log.e("folow_up_dt_view", String.valueOf(mn));
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                folow_up_dt_view.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                            }
                        }, yearNext, monthNext, dayNext);
//               



                picker.show();
```

Comment: when click on second datepicker then put the previous year,month,day then choose the next previous date

Comment: can you elaborate with an example

Comment: get text in the text view and give the second dialog picker same as first dialog picker where you give year , month , day

Comment: but will that date is reflected in the second datepicker???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the values from Calendar1 Instance to Second Date Picker Dialog you want to show like this,

```
datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            dateSetListener1,
            calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        datePickerDialog1.show();

datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(
            this, 
            dateSetListener2,
            calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
datePickerDialog2.show();
```

Comment: that works but there was one condition also like if i select 20 august from first date picker than I want before 20 august all the date should be disable in second date picker .....can you help me i this